# Does the 'such' relate to 'as'?

Tags: grammar, meaning

From [LONGMAN](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/such):

> **such**
> **6.** *formal*
> used to refer only to people or things of a particular group or kind
> **such ... as/who/that**
> *Such individuals who take up this role often find life frustrating.*
> **such of somebody/something as**
> *Such of you as wish to leave may do so now.*

According to the item,' as' functions as a pronoun.

Here is another example:

> Halley’s comet did not cause such a worldwide sensation in any
> historical sighting **as** did its return in 1910-1911.

Does 'as' function as a pronoun? If so, why is there an inversion of auxiliary verb?

Comment: ***as*** in the comet example has the sense of ***in that degree; to that extent***. For a shorter context: *This is not **such** a long sentence **as** [is] that.* Note that we often don't explicitly include the verb *(**did, is**]* after ***as*** in such contexts. I think the best "part of speech" (to the extent that's a useful concept here) is that it's a ***conjunction***. The "inversion" is a meaningless literary / stylistic "flourish". It could just as well have been the "default" sequence ***as its return did** in 1910*

Comment: *This is not **such** a short sentence **as** my first example [is a short sentence]*, if that makes the usage any clearer.

Comment: What does your question mean? If I answered, "yes", what would that tell you?

Comment: @gotube As I know, adverbs or prepositional phrases usually use the inversion and I have never seen a pronoun using the inversion. So, this usage confused me. With the answer of FumbleFingers, now I suddenly realize that 'such...as...' and 'as...as...' have the same usage but such is only used with noun phrases while the first as in 'as...as...' can be used with adjectives, adverbs, or something like that. From the sources I have collected ,the idea that    'such...as...' is like 'as...as...' makes sense, but if you have some other ideas ,you can tell me.